# Using method with self inside blocks

Tags: objective-c, block, retain-cycle

I need to execute same bunch of code in two blocks (I'm using ARC):

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[_dataProvider doA:^(NSError *error) {
    [weakSelf handleError:error];
}];
```

And in a different place i call:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[_dataProvider doB:^(NSError *error) {
    [weakSelf handleError:error];
}];
```

Then I have my handler:

```
- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Is it save to use it this way? Please do notice that `handleError:` method uses `self` inside. If not, then what is the proper approach here? BTW: self is a viewController and can be dealloced (doB: and doA: blocks are based on networking, so can be slow).

Comment: how do you mean _is it safe to use_? it won't blow your device up... so, yes, it is safe in that view.

Comment: it's not "completely" safe, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe to do this, even if many people a doing it like this.

You should use the "weakSelf" pattern with blocks when it is justified.
In your example the "weakSelf" pattern is not justified, because `self` don't have any `strong` reference to your `block`. You can use like this :

```
[_dataProvider doA:^(NSError *error) {
    // here you can use self, because you don't have any strong reference to your block

    [weakSelf handleError:error];
}];
```

Use "weakSelf" pattern if you have a `strong` reference to your `block` ( with a property or an instance variable for example) and your are capturing `self` inside the `block`, example :

```
 @property(strong) void(^)(void) completionBlock;
....

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; 

    self.completionBlock = ^{
      // Don't use "self" here, it will be captured by the block and a retain cycle will be created
      // But if we use "weakSelf" here many times, it risques that it will be nil at the end of the block
      // You should create an othere strong reference to the "weakSelf"
      __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf; 
      // here you use strongSelf ( and not "weakSelf" and especially not "self")
    };
```

Comment: I heard something similar. However xCode isn't agreeing with this as far as I understand- `[_someInstance doC:^(NSError *error) { self.index += 5; }];` (where `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;`). XCode claims `Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle`. I have neither property nor ivar for this block, why do I get the warning?

Comment: I will silence the warning by doing : #pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"

....your block here

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

Comment: So you claim this is a general warning and I shouldn't care about it in this specific case? I usually find warnings helpful and I'm afraid the warning have some 'truth' hidden behind it. However if you're sure in this case it's ok then I understand the pattern how it works.